# Firebase returning Optional() with Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

This code is now displaying data in the app as Optional('data') since updating to Swift 3.0. Any idea?

```
let ring1FightRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Ring1Fighting")


@IBOutlet weak var ring1Fighting: UILabel!
```

Here is the code in viewDidLoad

```
ring1FightRef.observe(.value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in self.ring1Fighting.text = (snap.value as AnyObject).description
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to unwrap the value that you recieve:-

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Ring1Fighting").observe(.value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in

        print((snap.value as! String))


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I hade the same issue before and here is what was my solution 
Just make it simple and change it to the following

self.labelName.text = snap.value as? String